# I'm trying to use Java's HttpURLConnection to do a "conditional get", but I never get a 304 status code

Tags: java, http, caching, http-caching

Here is my code:

```
    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) sourceURL.openConnection();
    if (cachedPage != null) {
        if (cachedPage.eTag != null) {
            conn.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", cachedPage.eTag);
        }
        conn.setIfModifiedSince(cachedPage.pageLastModified);
    }

    conn.connect();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        newCachedPage.eTag = conn.getHeaderField("ETag");
        newCachedPage.pageLastModified = conn.getHeaderFieldDate("Last-Modified", 0);

    } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
        // Never reaches here
    }
```

I never seem to get the HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED response code, even hitting the same server several times in quick succession - where there is definitely no change to the page.  Also, conn.getHeaderField("ETag") always seems to respond null, and sometimes conn.getHeaderFieldDate("Last-Modified", 0) returns 0.  I've tried this against a variety of web servers.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can only do it successfully if the server supports it. Perhaps it is using `Expires` instead for caching and/or expecting an `If-Not-Modified` request header? Or the server has buggy/poor support for it because the streaming code is written by a starter in a custom servlet? Investigate all response headers of a default HTTP GET request to learn what caching mechanisms the server seems to support. For in-depth background information about HTTP caching mechanisms, read this tutorial: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: The server I'm testing against is Wordpress on a fairly standard LAMP stack.  Is it really that rare for servers to support conditional get?

Comment: Uhm, why did you tag `servlets`? Anyway, how about the request headers you obtained?

Comment: Uhm, because I'm using servlets?  I was getting an Expires header, so I've modified my code to support that in addition to conditional get.

Comment: Oh, you're executing this `URLConnection` code inside a servlet method? Sorry, I didn't expect that. I then don't see how that tag is relevant as you would technically have exactly the same problem when doing so in a plain Java class with a `main()` method. Anyway, if you get an `Expires` header, then it just means that you shouldn't request anything until the specified expire time. If you get an `ETag` response header, then it means that you should be able to use `If-None-Match` to test it. If you get a `Last-Modified` response header, you should be able to use `If-Modified-Since` to test it.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you've got a point, I've removed the servlets tag.  Sounds like I'm now supporting the three mechanisms I need to support - just surprised that some of the servers I'm testing against don't seem to take advantage of it.  Hey ho.

Comment: Try on `http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico` (URL taken from this stackoverflow page request). It gives a `Last-Modified` header of `Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT`. If you send a new request with `If-Modified-Since` header of exactly that value, you should get a 304. At least, here it does.

Comment: I summarized the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're all dependent on the server config.

If you get an `Expires` response header, then it just means that you don't need to request anything until the specified expire time. If you get a `Last-Modified` response header, then it means that you should be able to use `If-Modified-Since` to test it. If you get an `ETag` response header, then it means that you should be able to use `If-None-Match` to test it.

Lets take http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico as an example (the Stackoverflow's favicon image):

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico").openConnection();
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFields());
```

This gives:

> {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], ETag=["9d9bd8b1165cb1:0"], Date=[Wed, 17 Aug 2011 17:57:07 GMT], Content-Length=[1150], Last-Modified=[Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT], Content-Type=[image/x-icon], Connection=[keep-alive], Accept-Ranges=[bytes], Server=[nginx/0.8.36], X-Cache=[HIT], Cache-Control=[max-age=604800]}

Now, do a [`If-Modified-Since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) with the same value as [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29):

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", "Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT");
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFields());
```

This gives as expected a 304:

> {null=[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified], ETag=["9d9bd8b1165cb1:0"], Date=[Wed, 17 Aug 2011 17:57:42 GMT], Last-Modified=[Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT], Connection=[keep-alive], Server=[nginx/0.8.36], X-Cache=[HIT], Cache-Control=[max-age=604800]}

Now, do a [`If-None-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) with the same value as [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19):

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", "9d9bd8b1165cb1:0");
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFields());
```

This gives *unexpectedly* a 200:

> {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], ETag=["9d9bd8b1165cb1:0"], Date=[Wed, 17 Aug 2011 18:01:42 GMT], Content-Length=[1150], Last-Modified=[Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT], Content-Type=[image/x-icon], Connection=[keep-alive], Accept-Ranges=[bytes], Server=[nginx/0.8.36], X-Cache=[HIT], Cache-Control=[max-age=604800]}

Even more surprising, when the both headers are set with random garbage value as `ETag`, the server still gives a 304. This is an indication that the `If-None-Match` is completely ignored by the server behind http://cdn3.sstatic.net. That might be a (proxy) configuration issue or be done fully awarely (not for obvious reasons imho).

Comment: Can please help me, I've tried using your method but never returns 304, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605425/http-conditional-get.

Answer (score -4):

Or shorter :)

Just try **set connection timeout other than 0**.

```
conn.setConnectionTimeout( 3000);
```

Do it after .openConnection()

```
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) sourceURL.openConnection();
conn.setConnectionTimeout( 3000);
```

If not set also readTimeout other than 0.

```
conn.setReadTimeout( 3000);
```