# HTTP Conditional GET

Tags: java, urlconnection

I'm trying to check if a file has been modified after a given date. I found this [I'm trying to use Java's HttpURLConnection to do a "conditional get", but I never get a 304 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095897/im-trying-to-use-javas-httpurlconnection-to-do-a-conditional-get-but-i-neve). which seemed like what I needed. 
But if I try:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://cdn3.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", "Wed, 06 Oct 2010 02:53:46 GMT");
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFields());
```

The output is:

```
{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], ETag=["087588e2bb5cd1:0"],
Date=[Wed, 28 Nov 2012 12:39:31 GMT], Content-Length=[1150],
Last-Modified=[Sun, 28 Oct 2012 16:44:54 GMT], Accept-Ranges=[bytes],
Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[image/x-icon], X-Cache=[HIT],
Server=[NetDNA-cache/2.2], Cache-Control=[max-age=604800]}
```

**Edit**

I've tried today's date but still doesn't return 304.

> Wed, 28 Nov 2012 12:59:56 GMT

It should return 304 but as you can see it doesn't, any help is appropriated.

Comment: If your request asks for something modified after 10/06/2010 and you get a 200 on a file modified on 10/28/2012, that's normal. Have you tried to change the If-Modified-Since date to something past 10/28/2012?

Comment: @mprivat I've tried Wed, 28 Nov 2012 12:59:56 GMT and it's returns the same output, no 304.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file *has* been modified. Change your `If-Modified-Since` header to something *after* the `Last-Modified` result.

I tried it (with curl) and this CDN seems to have trouble with dates. To get a `304` response to an `If-Modified-Since` request, you *need* to provide the exact `Last-Modified` date (Sun, 28 Oct 2012 16:44:54 GMT here). Needless to say this is evil behaviour from this CDN.

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to use something like this...

***connection.addRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", lastModified);***

Here is the Code:

```
try {
                    HttpResponseCache cache = responseCache.getInstalled();
                    cacheResponse = cache.get(uri, "GET",
                            new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
                    if (cacheResponse != null) {
                        Map<String, List<String>> headers = cacheResponse
                                .getHeaders();
                        List<String> eTagHeader = headers.get("ETag");
                        eTag = eTagHeader.get(0);
                        if (eTag != null) {
                            connection.addRequestProperty("If-None-Match", eTag);
                        }
                        if(headers.containsKey("Last-Modified")){
                            List<String> lastModifiedList = headers.get("Last-Modified");
                            if(null != lastModifiedList && !lastModifiedList.isEmpty()){
                                String lastModified = lastModifiedList.get(0);
                                if(null != lastModified){ connection.addRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", lastModified);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, String.format("Cannot read from cache.", url),
                            e1);
                }
```